# local file system access - solutions?

Tags: javascript, vba, file, system, local

2nd question I've posted.  still very new to web programming so excuse my ignorance.

I have a web based javascript which accesses a users Gmail account and downloads attachments to the local downloads folder as assigned in Chrome.

These files are then manually transferred to another directory and an Excel VBA script processes the files.

I'd like to be able to skip the manual transfer step and save the files directly to to the folder that Excel is looking at.  I can get the Excel script to move the files but it only works if the user has not changed the Chrome default downloads folder location so it's not foolproof.

I believe this is impossible with javascript but is it possible with other languages or do I need a completely different approach? if it is possible with other languages which one and which methods do I need to be looking at?

This is the download section of the code as it stands at the minute at the request of a user OmegaStripes below:

```
<html>

<head>Google Drive File Download Process:
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';//removed for privacy
        var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

        /**
         * Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
         */

        function handleClientLoad() {
            window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
        }

        /**
         * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
         */

        function checkAuth() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                    'scope': SCOPES,
                    'immediate': true
                },
                handleAuthResult);
        }

        /**
         * Called when authorization server replies.
         *
         */

        function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
            var authButton = document.getElementById('authorizeButton');
            var filePicker = document.getElementById('filePicker');
            authButton.style.display = 'none';
            filePicker.style.display = 'none';
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.
                filePicker.style.display = 'block';
                filePicker.onclick = downloadFile; // to allow for manual start of downloads
                window.setTimeout(downloadFile(), 5000);

            } else {
                // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the authorization flow.
                authButton.style.display = 'block';
                authButton.onclick = function() {
                    gapi.auth.authorize({
                            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                            'scope': SCOPES,
                            'immediate': false
                        },
                        handleAuthResult);
                };
            }
        }

        /**
         * Start the file download.
         *
         *
         */

        function downloadFile() {
            console.log("call drive api");
            gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);
        }




        function makeRequest() {
            console.log("make request");
            var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list();
            request.execute(function(resp) {

                var x = []; //array for revised list of files to only include those not in the trash and those which have a suffix #FHM#
                for (i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                    if (resp.items[i].labels.trashed != true && resp.items[i].title.substring(0, 5) == "#FHM#") {
                        x.push([resp.items[i].title, resp.items[i].webContentLink, resp.items[i].id]);
                    }
                }

                if (x.length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("filePicker").value = "There are no files to download";
                }


                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    console.log(x.length);
                    var dlUrl = x[i][1];
                    fileIdentity = x[i][2];
                    downloadUrl(dlUrl);
                    trashFile(fileIdentity);

                    filePicker.style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("bodyText").innerHTML = "<br>Download " + (i + 1) + " of " + x.length + " completed.";
                }


            });

            //window.setTimeout(function() {
            //    self.close;
            //}, 5000);

        }

        function downloadUrl(url) {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.src = url;
            iframe.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }

        function trashFile(id) {
            var requestTrash = gapi.client.drive.files.trash({
                    'fileId': id
                });
            requestTrash.execute(function(resp) {});
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <!--Add buttons for the user to start the process -->
    <input type="button" id="filePicker" style="display: none" value="If download does not start after 5 seconds, click here" />
    <input type="button" id="authorizeButton" style="display: none" value="Authorize" />
     <b id="bodyText"></b>
</body>
```

thanks

Comment: Could you share your web based javascript, it might be implemented using HTA / JScript which have full access to FS, or converted and put directly into your VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could try to copy the files and if unsuccessful, ask the user to provide the correct path to the extracted file(s). You are right it cannot be done by Javascript. If you want to avoid having to ask the user for the path, you can implement a module to search for the file.

Is there a way you could know whether a file was extracted? If so, you can use this knowledge to know whether the lack of successful copying should trigger a file search or file path requesting.

Comment: yeah good idea.  I can know if the file is there as all files a renamed to include the suffix #FHM# so that's easy to test.  so I'll check the standard download location for files with #FHM# then do a search if not - Nice thanks